# Use PIN authentication by default to unlock Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Ok, so I've setup my Windows 8 to use live account, I have rather complex password there (and I was used to simple password to lock my workstation because I only needed to prevent my non-computer family from access). I welcomed PIN password and loved it but... how do I set is as default method to unlock station? right now I have to use password or explicitly select PIN and then enter pin which makes the whole process longer...